# jquery resize loses 'this' reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming jquery is included:

```
   function FixedPoint(bgWidth) {
        this.bgWidth= bgWidth;

        this.plot();
        $(window).resize(this.plot);

    }

    FixedPoint.prototype.plot = function() {

        console.log(this.bgWidth); //This is undefined when called by resize

    }

    var pt1 = new FixedPoint(1920);
```

When plot() is being called in the constructor or after the initialization everything is ok, but when plot() is being called by resize function, it can no longer access instance variables via 'this'.

I can call resize out side of the constructor to fix this, but want to have it in the class for tidiness.

Comment: Yes, that is expected. `this` inside is the target of the event when you pass that function as a callback to an event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(window).resize(this.plot);` The method `this.plot` is getting invoked from within the `window` context. So this is the expected behavior. `this` will point to the window object instead of `FixedPoint`. You can use Ecmascript5 [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to explicitly bind the context.

```
      $(window).resize(this.plot.bind(this));
```

With jquery you can use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to do the same thing.

Just to give more insight, `this` context is set based on where the method was invoked from (except for the bound functions). Here this would have got invoked from within the `resize` method of window object, where `this` refers to window.

Another hacky way is to use anonymous callback function and use cached this variable.

```
 function FixedPoint(bgWidth) {
     this.bgWidth = bgWidth;
     var self = this; //cache it here
     $(window).resize(function () {
         self.plot(); //invoke with self.
     });
 }
```

Comment: Nice, works. Thank you. Will accept it as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: @Offspring2099 Read the `bind` link pasted in my answer. For support in some browsers you need to add the shim.